# Access localhost with physical Android device

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to access the nginx webservice that I run on my `http://localhost:8000/test` using my physical Android device.

But it does not work. Either with `http://localhost:8000/test` or `http://10.0.2.2:8000/test`.

I get this error message:

> Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Network is
>   unreachable, errno = 101, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 40914

Answer (score 0):

run this command in terminal:

```
ifconfig | grep mask
```

In second line display mask `IP` you can use.
[image]